# No sound when running in Parallels 6

Tags: 10.10, sound, mac, parallels

I'm getting no sound from my Ubuntu 10.10 Desktop install on Parallels 6. I have enabled User sound, and checked my inputs and outputs. I am using an iMac 2.66GHz i5.

Comment: Is your iMac running Ubuntu or Mac OS X?

Comment: Same here, My mac is running mac os 10.6, parallels 6 and ubuntu 10.04 (Guest OS)

Comment: try virtualbox.

Comment: Virtualbox works perfectly. Thanks @RolandTaylor

Answer (score 1):

I don't normally suggest alternatives in questions like this, but try using [Virtual Box](http://www.virtualbox.org/) instead. Parallels is a nice bit of software, but Virtual Box works better with Linux as far as I know.